# What is cosine to the power of zero?

Tags: calculus, integration, trigonometry

I was doing a question relates to substitution rule under integration.

The question is as follow:

Evaluate $\int{1\over{(1+x^2)^n}}dx, n\in \mathbb{Z}^+$

We have seen that $(\tan^{-1}x)'=\frac{1}{1+x^2}$

Let $x= \tan t, t\in(-\frac{\pi}{2},\frac{\pi}{2})$. Then $\frac{dx}{dt}=\sec^2t$

$$\int\frac{1}{(1+x^2)^n}dx=\int\frac{1}{(1+tan^2t)^n}\sec^2tdt$$
$$=\int\frac{\sec^2t}{\sec^{2n}t}dt=\int\cos^{2n-2}tdt$$

so I got the final answer $\cos^{2n -2} (t) dt$, but the question continues to ask what's the integral when $n=1$.

I substitute $n=1$, and I got $\cos^0 (t)$ which is totally unfamiliar to me.

So what is $\cos^0 (t)$ ?

Comment: Isn't that simply $1$?

Comment: @user33448687 when $n=1$ cant you right away right it as $\arctan (x)$

Answer (score 13, accepted):

$\cos^0(t) = 1$ if $\cos t \ne 0$ and undefined else, so $\int \cos^0 t \ \mathrm dt = \int 1 \ \mathrm dt = t + C$. This results in
$$\int \frac1{(1+x^2)^1} \ \mathrm dx = t + C= \arctan x + C$$
wich is consistent with what you know. Note that $\arctan$ is a nicer way of writing $\tan^{-1}$.

Comment: $\arctan$ is also a less misleading way of writing $\tan^{-1}$: The latter borrows the notation $\cdot^{-1}$ used for function inverses, but $\arctan$ is *not* the inverse of $\tan$ (which is not injective and hence has no inverse) but rather the inverse of the *restriction* of $\tan$ to $(-\frac{\pi}{2}, \frac{\pi}{2})$.

Comment: Domains'll getcha every time.

Comment: I don't understand why you write "undefined else": $0^0$ is defined as $1$. And that's important, how would you write power series without this definition? (As in $\exp(x) = \sum_{n=0}^\infty x^n/n!$)

Comment: @HendrikVogt The definition $0^0 = 1$ must be treated with care, because it doesn't work with limits. That's why it usually remains undefined.

Comment: @AlexR: In analysis, one always defines $0^0=1$, but you're right that one has to keep in mind that $(x,y)\mapsto x^y$ is not continuous at $(0,0)$. In set theory, $0^0=1$ since $0^0=\varnothing^\varnothing=\{\varnothing\}$. I'm not 100% sure about other areas of mathematics. Where does it remain undefined, usually?

Comment: @HendrikVogt Whenever we have some context where it's nit clear that the limit value of the form $0^0$ is $1$. In this patricular case we could argue that the limit does exist and is $1$, but why bother since the solution doesn't depend on it.

Comment: @AlexR: I'd really like to see a reference to a book where they leave $0^0$ undefined. The reason for my comment was the following: I've been teaching calculus for years, and many students had learned in school that $0^0$ is undefined. Then suddenly we have power series and stuff like that where $0^0$ appears naturally, and one needs to know that it's equal to $1$. So call it my mission to bring the gospel $0^0=1$ to the world.

Answer (score 8):

For every non-zero number $x$, you have $x^0=1$

Comment: non-zero complex number, to be exact.